# How to tell NeoVim to use “python” instead of “python3”?

Tags: neovim, linux, python

Im using `pyenv` to administer my python versions (Im on Manjaro Linux) and the command for python on my system is `python` but nvim wants to use python3. How can I change it?

Error:

```
[coc.nvim] Error on execute python script: request error nvim_command - Vim(pyxf
ile):E319: No "python3" provider found. Run ":checkhealth provider"
```

Here is a prt of my `init.vim` file:

```bash
" coc config
let g:coc_global_extensions = [
  \ 'coc-snippets',
  \ 'coc-pairs',
  \ 'coc-tsserver',
  \ 'coc-eslint', 
  \ 'coc-prettier', 
  \ 'coc-json', 
  \ 'coc-sh',
  \ 'coc-clangd',
  \ 'coc-cmake',
  \ 'coc-jedi'
  \ ]
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because my system does not name the default python interpreter as `python3`, but as `python` I simply added a shell alias:

```bash
alias python3='python'
```

Answer (score 1):

If nvim works like Vim on this topic, as a I see `pyxfile` in your error message, you should be able to force [`'pyxversion'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27pyxversion%27) to 2 in your `.vimrc` (or equivalent with nvim)

```
set pyxversion=2
```

This may cause troubles with plugins that explicitly request `:py3` commands as it would not longer be available once the first use of a `:py` or `:pyx` command has been issued.

Comment: I dont have something called `.vimrc`. I have files like that: `ls -la | grep vim                                               
.nvim
.vim
.viminfo` which one should i use?

Comment: The entry point. `init.vim` may be?

Comment: Yes, I do have `init.vim` i place my configs there. Sorry Im new to vim and don't know its structure

Comment: With vim, I know. With nvim, it's just wild guesses on my part.

Comment: I added it and now I get this: 
`[coc.nvim] Error on execute python script: request error nvim_command - Vim(pyxf
ile):E319: No "python" provider found. Run ":checkhealth provider"`
It cannot find python for some reason

Comment: Given the new error message I wonder  whether or environment is compatible with either version of python. You can try with `:version` to see whether its compatible with either version of pthon. You can try may be the command suggested in the error message. Or to `:echomsg has('python')` in a first session of nvim, at the start of you r init file. Then `:echomsg has('python3')` instead. This should give results similar to `:version` I guess

Comment: Okay so what I did is deleted that set pyxversion and at the beginning of my `.zshrc` I added an alias for python3=python and it works. If you could edit your answer to describe that I will accept it. Thank you, I wouldn't discover the inner working of that without :version and :checkhealth

Answer (score 1):

i solved mine by doing this `python -m pip --user --upgrade pynvim`.
PyNvim is a provider for python in NVIM

and later in the config file at `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` add this line saying which python to use `let g:python3_host_prog = '/usr/bin/python'`

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: thanks, mate... :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved that issue by installing `pynvim` package for all Python 3 releases that was described in:
`:checkhealth provider`

In my system, I have python3.10 and python3.9, so I run:

```
python3.10 -m pip install --user pynvim
python3.9 -m pip install --user pynvim
```